# How can I prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{kr^{k-1}} = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{(1-r)^2} - (n+1)\frac{r^n}{1-r}$ by induction?

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

Given the identity [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas), I don't know how to prove it.

$(k+1)r^k + (\frac{1-r^{k+1}}{(1-r)^2} - (k+1)\frac{r^k}{1-r}),$ which I can simplify to get $\frac{1-r^{k+2}}{(1-r)^2} - (k+2)\frac{r^{k+1}}{1-r}$.

But it seems not to help.

Comment: @amWhy I think OP is saying they want to do that simplification (since that would conclude the proof) but are unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
&(k+1)r^k + \frac{1-r^{k+1}}{(1-r)^2} - (k+1) \frac{r^k}{1-r}
\\
&= \frac{1-r^{k+1}}{(1-r)^2} - (k+1) \frac{r^{k+1}}{1-r}
\\
&= \frac{1-r^{k+1}}{(1-r)^2} +  \frac{r^{k+1}}{1-r} - (k+2) \frac{r^{k+1}}{1-r}
\\
&= \frac{1-r^{k+2}}{(1-r)^2} - (k+2) \frac{r^{k+1}}{1-r}.
\end{align}